# Windows xp blinking under score after bios

Tags: windows-xp, boot, cursor

so this is for an older pc I have to repair for a friend.

The pc has an hdd of about 60 something gb, It uses win xp and let's say 60-70% of the boots it hangs on showing only an underscore bilking line after bios screen, rest of the times it boots fine or the computer shuts down on xp loading screen.

Sometimes if you let it alone while the underscore is blinking, it will boot after a while, like a few minutes, some times it won't boot at all even if you give him more time, like one hour.

When it boots successfully the pc seems to work fine.

I think it's a bad hard disk and i'm about to suggest buying a new one and switching it but I don't have enough experience and i would hate making him buy a new hdd and not solving the problem.

anyone has any tips?

I know there are other topics about blinking underscores or cursors while xp is booting but the issues about the pc shutting itself down or sometimes booting really freaks me out.

Can't format everything and re install until about 10 days from now, cause the dude has some program for his business on this pc and I have to migrate it when the next computer arrives, however he needs to use it until then.

so please advise, thx.

Comment: We need SMART test result to help

Comment: well, not everybody is smart like you good sir.If you are willing to help then help me get these "smart" test results.I'm telling what I have observed and comed here cause I don't know more!that's the point of this site, isn't it? Now what is your point?help or be a smart ass?

Comment: S.M.A.R.T not "smart" there was a reason it was all capital letters I am only trying to help.  Without the S.M.A.R.T data I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the event viewer.  It will show hardware and software issues.  Open the Control Panel, then Administrative tools, and you'll see it there.  Under System, it should have messages regarding any drive errors.

Edited to say:  Back the system up ASAP regardless of what you see there.

Comment: hi, thanks for the clear answer.i don't have access to the pc right now but I will have tomorrow.What other tools could/should I use to properly diagnose the problem?

Comment: The Ultimate Boot CD was always a go to diagnostic tool for me in the past.  I haven't used it in a while, so I'm not sure how up to date it is for newer hardware.